# Starting MySQL Error on Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, osx-snow-leopard

### ORIGINAL POST

I just erased and re-installed Snow Leopard. I installed MySQL 5.1.48 64-bit clean. I'm having issues with the MySQL server... when I boot the computer and log in, the server is not running. I tried to start it using the preference pane by clicking "Start MySQL Server", but all it did was highlight the button blue and think for like a minute, and then the button went back to normal and nothing happened.

I then tried starting it from the terminal:

```
Hristo$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
.....................................................................
ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

so I checked the status:

```
Hristo$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server status
Password:
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: line 418: pidof: command not found
 ERROR! MySQL is not running
```

I tried this:

```
Hristo$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

So I'm not sure what to do. When I first installed, the server was working but I went to the preference pane to try and stop it… and the same thing happened… I clicked the "Stop MysQL Server" button, it did some thinking, then nothing. So I restarted the computer and now I'm having the above problems and apparently, the mysql.sock file is not in /tmp/ anymore. It was there when I installed, and it is not there after I restarted the computer.

Any ideas?

### **UPDATE**

This is my `/etc/my.cnf` file.

```
[client]
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

### **UPDATE 2**

When setting up Apache, PHP, and MySQL, I followed these instructions: http://superfancy.net/coding/php-mysql-apache-in-mac-osx-leopard/ Right now, if I remove the MySQL configuration file, things seem to work fine. But when `my.cnf` exists in `/etc/`, things don't work. The MySQL verion is:

```
Hristo$ mysql --version
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.46, for apple-darwin9.8.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

### **UPDATE 3**

mysql.err:

```
100706 11:38:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
100706 11:38:36 [Warning] '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ''--general_log'/'--general_log_file'' instead.
100706 11:38:36 [Warning] '--log_slow_queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ''--slow_query_log'/'--slow_query_log_file'' instead.
100706 11:38:36 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
100706 11:38:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
100706 11:38:36  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 69987
100706 11:38:36 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
100706 11:38:36 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock ?
100706 11:38:36 [ERROR] Aborting

100706 11:38:36  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
100706 11:38:41  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 69987
100706 11:38:41 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

mysql.log:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.1.46-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

Comment: What's in your `/etc/my.cnf`?

Comment: @Dan... I updated my post with the content of the `my.cnf` file.

Comment: Also, what does `mysql --version` shoot out for you?

Comment: Can you also add logging to your `my.cnf`? I.e. add 

    `log=/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`,
    `log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql.err` and
    `log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/slow-queries.log`

to your `[mysql]` grouping. Don't forget to `touch` those files so that they exist on your system and give mysql privileges to write to them. Once you do that, start mysql from the command line. In your `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` directory, run `./mysqld_safe --user=mysql &` and let us know what is fed into the log.

Comment: @Dan... I added updates to my original post. Please refer to updates 2 and 3 for the mysql version and the .err and .log files.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot to mention, you should probably run `sudo ./mysqld_safe --user=mysql` instead of what I mentioned above.

Comment: Hmm, try `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_install_db --force`. Maybe the databases weren't created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is an error somewhere in your my.cnf file.

Try to take one of the stock my.cnf files or add options for user, pid-file, port, basedir, datadir, tmpdir under [mysqld] section (here's a quote of basic mysqld settings on linux machine, for OS X maybe [this](http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/create-mysql-configuration-file-mycnf-on-mamp.html) will help)

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
skip-external-locking

#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: The reason I have the my.cnf file the way it is posted above is because of the instructions I followed here: http://superfancy.net/coding/php-mysql-apache-in-mac-osx-leopard/ When I was setting up MySQL, I followed the instructions under the **"Getting MySQL and PHP to communicate"** section. Any suggestions on the `socket` settings for the default config file?

Comment: you said that the server starts if you don't use my.cnf file; in that case start it like that and then run `mysql --help` to get info on which actual cnf file is used and what are the values of various variables that are set from it. You can take the value of `socket` from here.

Answer (score 16):

Install homebrew package manager with the quick install method
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Then from terminal

`brew install mysql`

and follow the short list of directions that follow the installation

to see the instructions again

`brew info mysql`

Comment: No problem. Its one of the nicest features of os x :)

Comment: do you know where the my.cnf file is after you install? i looked in all the usual places.

Comment: Thank you for saving me a headache. I have developed a very negative Pavlovian response from so many bad installs of mysql.

Comment: I had installed using homebrew, but was still getting the same error message as the question asker. I realized I did not run the steps "Set up databases with: (1) unset TMPDIR (2) mysql_install_db" from `brew info mysql`... After running these two commands, MySQL would start, and I then followed that up with `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.1.55/bin/mysql_secure_installation` to secure the installation.

Comment: Also make sure when you do mysql_install_db, that you're in the top level of the mysql directory (/usr/local/Cellar/mysql) for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else runs into this infuriating issue.....

Homebrew install of mysql, snow leopard (most recent update)

make sure your `/usr/local/var/mysql` and all subdirs is owned by current user!

```
sudo chown -R <user> /usr/local/var/mysql
```

if you want to startup mysql using the `/etc/my.cnf` and you are specifying something like

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

your server will never start. I believe MySql 5.5.x has this set by default. Comment this line out in your my.cnf file and 
mysql.server start should do the trick.

Comment: Just wanted to note on Mountain Lion this is a good solution as well

Answer (score 3):

The file is supposed to be recreated every time that MySQL is loaded, but sometimes permissions will get in the way. Try manually creating /tmp/mysql.sock

On linux the command would be:

`sudo touch /tmp/mysqld.sock`

Then set the correct owner:
`sudo chown mysql:mysql /tmp/mysqld.sock`

I assume command line on a mac would be the same.

Comment: Yes, the commands are the same. However, this didn't work. I restarted and the file was gone again. I re-touch'd it, re-chown'd, and then tried starting MySQL... then the file was gone again.

Comment: Make sure your myqsl config file is still valid after the reinstall.

Comment: .. I'm sorry, but what do you mean by valid?

Comment: Just make sure that none of the directories or paths have changed. I've done that a few times.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine that some of these other solutions will be appropriate for some other people, but I had all of these same symptoms (including the `line 418: pidof: command not found` issue), but my root cause was a little different.

I had a working `/etc/my.cnf` file that abruptly stopped working, so I was confident the problem was not my config. It turned out that a subdirectory under `/usr/local/var/mysql/` was owned by _mysql:staff, when it should have been owned by me. After running `chown -R 'whoami' /usr/local/var/mysql/`, all was right with the world.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to unlock that pid process then. stop mysql by `srvice mysql stop`
After that type this command `ps-ef| grep mysql` It will show two pid of sql. kill both by 
`kill -9 pid 1 pid2` then start sql by `service mysql start`.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an error message:

```
line 418: pidof: command not found
```

Do you have `pidof` installed? [Its manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) says:

> pidof is simply a (symbolic) link to the killall5 program, which should also be located in /sbin

Perhaps the symlink doesn't exist or killall5 is not installed on your Mac OS?

Comment: There is no manual entry for `pidof`... `Hristo$ man pidof No manual entry for pidof`. Also, there is a `killall` in `/usr/bin` but not in `/usr/sbin`

Comment: Try `which pidof` - if you don't get anything, this can be the reason. I don't know how killall5 is (dis)similar to killall and whether it can be used interchangeably...

Comment: `which pidof` returns nothing. I'll look into what it is and how to install it. Any suggestions?

Comment: On my Linux system, it seems to be in a package `sysvinit-utils`: /bin/pidof ; see if you have a similar package (not sure if it's available in Mac OS, but I'd think it should be).

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how OS X installation works, but this seems to be the thing you're looking for: http://osx.iusethis.com/app/pidof

Comment: Ok... I installed the `pidof` utility and the error `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: line 418: pidof: command not found` doesn't show up anymore. But the server still doesn't work... after I restart, I can't start the server... still getting `ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.`

Comment: `pidof` isn't the problem. The `mysql.server` script is just calling that to find the pid of the MySQL process.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-server.html

Quoting David Tonhofer:

> ```
> And also add
> -----------
> echo "Manager PID file is $pid_file, Server PID file is $server_pid_file"
> -----------
> directly before the line 'case "$mode" in'
> for some great debugging justice.
> ```

My initial guess was that the mysqld doesn't have permission to update / delete its pidfile, and probably there is a left-over pidfile that needs to be removed by hand. But "great debugging justice" sounds too good to miss. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it as a part of [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) . That will install a mysql server in a different location ( Applications/MAMP/mysql along with apache etc. Then you can just use the widget to start it. You can also monitor the activity with the acitivity monitor (Applications/utilities) . Besides:

Deleting: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid

and restarting does help often.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you installed view homebrew, try

```
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db
```

Comment: @Scott... I did this a long time ago, but I don't remember anything about "homebrew".